# SQL Join Query VB (Pretty Sumple, I'm just learning)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to make a query which has the same field in table A & table B.  Then table B has the same field as table C.  I want to left join all tables on table A.  Is this possible?  If yes, how close is my code to doing it?

```
    Try
            objConn = DBAccess.GetConnection
            strBlder.Append("SELECT ")
            strBlder.Append("FLD_NM, DATA_TYPE_CD, XML_PATH_TX, UPDT_USER_ID_NR, DOC_TMPL_FLD_ID_NR  ")
            strBlder.Append("FROM ")
            strBlder.Append("LLC.[LLCW10_DCTMPFLD_TB] LEFT JOIN LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping] ")
            strBlder.Append("ON LLC.[LLCW10_DCTMPFLD_TB].DOC_TMPL_FLD_ID_NR = LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping].DocumentTemplateFieldID ")
            strBlder.Append("& LEFT JOIN LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping] ")
            strBlder.Append("ON LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping].FieldMappingStatusID = LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMappingStatus].FieldMappingStatusID ")

            strBlder.Append("ORDER BY FLD_NM ;")
            dsData = DBAccess.ExecuteDataTable(objConn, CommandType.Text, strBlder.ToString())
            'execute non query - takes sp name
```

Comment: remove the & at the beginning of line 8. What happens when you run the query?

Comment: Now that I removed the & (thank you for that), I get:
The objects "LLC.DataMapTool_FieldMapping" and "LLC.DataMapTool_FieldMapping" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting(after removing the `&`) is because `LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping]` is repeated and thats a problem. Instead of your `from` clause try something like:

`FROM (LLC.[LLCW10_DCTMPFLD_TB] LEFT JOIN LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping] ON LLC.[LLCW10_DCTMPFLD_TB].DOC_TMPL_FLD_ID_NR = LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping].DocumentTemplateFieldID)
LEFT JOIN LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMappingStatus] ON LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMappingStatus].FieldMappingStatusID = LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping].FieldMappingStatusID`

Note that the `LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping]` is referenced in the first join and then only the `.FieldMappingStatusID` field is referenced in the second join. Your initial query would have been trying to add the same table to the query twice without giving it an alias which confuses the query analyzer.

Basically the new `from` clause will attach the first two tables together then attach the third table onto the result of the first join.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me, but there is that strange `&` before the `LEFT JOIN LLC.[DataMapTool_FieldMapping]` ... take that out.

Comment: Now that I removed the & (thank you for that), I get: The objects "LLC.DataMapTool_FieldMapping" and "LLC.DataMapTool_FieldMapping" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them.